Version Control - TortoiseSVN (subversion) - Tunnels in ConfigDir config not Working
A tunnel in the [tunnels] section of the config file has no effect.
1. TortoiseSVN context menu -> Settings Dialog -> Advanced
Set ConfigDir to C:\example_dir
2. Edit config (file) in C:\example_dir
[tunnels]
alt-ssh = ssh -i C:\example\filepath\to\private-key

3. Test tunnel using svn list command at command prompt.
svn list svn+alt-ssh://some_domain.xyz/C:/path/to/repository

Expected list of repository files but instead the following errors are shown:
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL ...
svn: E125002: Undefined tunnel scheme 'alt-ssh'
If the same tunnel, alt-ssh, is set in the default config file, the same svn list... command works.
I have also tested that the ConfigDir config file is working in general: In the config file that ConfigDir points to, I changed global-ignores in the [miscellany] section and it works.

Years ago, we had issues with whitespace around the equal sign in Subversion's config. Can you give alt-ssh=ssh -i ... (without spaces around =) a try?

I tried as you showed, plus combinations of space on either side, and made no difference. Thank you for the suggestion though. Note that the spacing, as shown in my question, does work in the config file that is in the default location.

They seem to have it improved in the mean time, good to know. It was worth a shot.

Yes, the README in the config dir, states that spaces are allowed so it's intentional. Note also, that I think that I determined why svn list ... didn't use the config file in the ConfigDir location and I added my findings as an answer here.

I think that I have determined my misunderstanding. Apparently, a setting to change the directory of the config file isn't part of the base svn package. However, client applications that use the svn API can offer the setting. E.g. TortoiseSvn offers the ConfigDir setting. Such a setting isn't used by the base svn package, only the client app (e.g. GUI such as TortoiseSvn) that offers the setting would use the new location of the config file.
For example, the TortoiseSvn shell UI does appear to find the tunnel setting in the config file:
C:\example_dir\config.
However, setting the TortoiseSvn ConfigDir value doesn't change the location of the config file for the svn command line. The svn command line is part of the base svn package. E.g., The snv list ... command line still uses the default config file location and so it doesn't see the tunnel setting. The command line does accept a --config-dir <dir> arg.
E.g.,
svn list --config-dir C:\example_dir svn+alt-ssh://some_domain.xyz/C:/path/to/repository
works.
The --config-dir arg is available for many of the svn command line commands:
https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw
However, the base svn package doesn't appear to have an option to change the config file directory permanently. Client apps such as TortoiseSvn that use the base svn API can provide this feature. For example, .NET Rider also has an option the specify a non-default directory for the svn config file and when I tried it, it worked, and that's what led me to this discovery.
(In my original question, when I said that I had proved that the TortoiseSvn ConfigDir setting worked by changing global-ignores, I had used the TortoiseSvn UI to test, so it did use the ConfigDir setting. I wasn't aware that the command line was not also using the global-ignores setting, because the command line commands [e.g. list] didn't use the correct tunnel setting and thus only indicated the general repository access failure [at that point, more specific testing was not possible].)
It can be a bit confusing so to summarize and simplify: Client apps that use the svn API such as TortoiseSvn, VisualSvn, and .NET Rider, can provide a setting to change the config file location. However, that config file location won't be used by the command line commands that are part of the base svn package.
